# Menu Block - stopping displaying children after a specific level

Tags: entities, navigation

So I am using Menu Block 7.23 and it is working awesome, I have it setup to start at 2nd level to show the children of the active menu, and if no children show active menu with max depth of 1 which has been working great.

I have been asked to make this navigation now, stop displaying the children after the 3rd level and I am not sure how to handle that in Menu Block configurations. I see there is a start level, but not a stop level. Here is an example of my heirarchy:

-Solutions
--Enterprise
---Profile Management
----Online/Offline

So essentially when going to Solutions it would show Enterprise, when going to Enterprise it would show Profile Management, but on Profile Management they do not want Online/Offline to appear, they want Profile Management to remain as the side menu. They want the breadcrumb to show the whole path on Online/Offline so I cannot just disable it from navigation, it needs to be part of the menu structure.

They want to just put reference links to Online/Offline in Profile Management page content, and on Online/Offline it would keep the Profile Management side menu.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'display:none' in the css as a solution.  I think using Nth-child would help achieve what you need http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your solution, I still want the side bar menu to appear on Online/Offline, I just want it to be the menu of the Profile Management. As opposed to the levels above needing to show the children. I basically want to stop showing children items after level 3 and just show that level on all pages after level 3. Hope that clarifies a bit more.

Comment: Ah! Ok what your asking has more to it than what I thought.   What I was getting at is using something like.   #nav ul ul ul ul { display:none;} . Would hide the child navigation.  If you want it to then appear on some pages I suppose it would probably be possible to engineer some php code that checks your page hierarchy .  You could do that in Sass . It's not something I've had to do so this is just in theory.

Comment: Hi Deejay, thanks for responding back, so do you know any place that would be able to help me write php to help me achieve this or how I would go about using Sass, I have never used Sass before.

Comment: There's some pretty helpful vids on YouTube on it :). http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HN0i9cYekKY

Comment: Thank you for the link, I do see how powerful sass can be but I am not knowledgeable enough to apply this alone.